# Firebase preview channels quota reached

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

We are using firebase preview channels in CI pipelines but now I've got this error message and I can't find any information about limits of preview channels..

`HTTP Error: 429, Couldn't create channel on 'projects/ID/sites/my-site': channel quota reached`

Comment: I'm not sure what the quota for preview channels is, but it seems you've exhausted it. Delete some of your preview channels, and try again. If that doesn't help, I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. It'd help there if you let them know how many previews you've made in the past few days.

Comment: Looks like the quota is 50.

Answer (score 0):

if you are deploying many times, try to set the expiration on your previews to just a few days:

```
...
with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
          expires: 3d
          projectId: '${{ projectId }}'
```

also check recurrency and sizes of your deployments and compare it with your configuration in your [gcp service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

Answer (score -1):

In firebase there is an limitation in it's storage. If you are using it frequently you may full storage that is allocated to you. Now you have to free up the some space in your firebase project. For that you can do the following

1. Delete the unwanted preview channels
2. Limit the no of veriosn should be maintained as mentioned below.

In Firebase, the last 10 versions of live and preview channel files were stored by default. You can change those settings in the firebase console by clicking the three dots on the right side then change 10 to your option. Also, do the same for preview chanels, For preview channel, you have to change each channel separately. For that click the date showing in the preview channel. You an see the same option

This may not remove the existing the data. But it will not store the upcoming channels version which is older that you set here.

[image]